# AWS freeRtos "failed to provision device certificate error:48"

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, freertos, stm32ldiscovery

I am new to AWS IoT and working with **STM32L475** Discovery kit board and trying to run the AWS freertos demo for the board based on the [AWS getting started guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/freertos/latest/userguide/getting_started_st.html).I followed all the steps provided in the AWS documentation but encountering the following error.

I had checked the AWS credentials and they are correct. I used the quick connect method to register my board and create the Iot Thing. I also Erased the flash memory before debugging the project thinking that might be causing the issue.

I am using **System workbench on windows 10 (64 bit)** for the project and Teraterm serial terminal with speed setting 115200

Could anyone please let me know how to resolve this issue? Thanks is advance.

````
1 532 [Tmr Svc] Write certificate...
2 541 [Tmr Svc] ERROR: Failed to provision certificate 48
3 547 [Tmr Svc] ERROR: Failed to provision private key 48
4 8978 [Tmr Svc] WiFi connected to AP NETGEAR30.
5 8982 [Tmr Svc] IP Address acquired 192.168.0.11
6 8987 [Tmr Svc] WiFi firmware version is: C3.5.2.5
7 8991 [Tmr Svc] WiFi firmware is up-to-date.```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please double check that you downloaded the correct firmware from the Inventek website: https://www.inventeksys.com/iwin/firmware/

The one you need to download is the third link marked as ***"New STM32L4 Discovery kit IoT node (B-L475E-IOT01A) ISM43362-M3G-L44-SPI-C3.5.2.5.STM SPI Firmware (unzip for bin file)"***.  Here is the direct download link for the same: https://www.inventeksys.com/iwin/wp-content/uploads/ISM43362_M3G_L44_SPI_C3.5.2.5.STM_.zip

Note that you do not need to rename any file or change script if you download the correct firmware.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like (from the second and third log messages) your credentials are incorrect.

Quick Connect should provide you with a Credentials.zip file to download.  After unzipping it, you should place the aws_clientcredential.h and aws_clientcredential_keys.h files in the demos/include directory of the Amazon FreeRTOS project (replace the same files already in that directory).

Comment: thanks for your response but I did this step already and still facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you might not have the "STM" version of the WiFi firmware (There was a [recent change](https://github.com/aws/amazon-freertos/commit/5a9f4db9c68b90a2deebe31668ee9a1fbc764b88) to check for that version specifically).

Have you tried updating the firmware using the instructions found under the troubleshooting section [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/freertos/latest/userguide/getting_started_st.html) --> the console should say that the version is C3.5.2.5.**STM** after doing that.

Comment: Yes, I updated the firmware as mentioned on the Aws site and the version is C3.5.2.5

Comment: It needs to be C3.5.2.5.STM  --> if the .STM is not there it is not the right version of the firmware.

Comment: Thank you for your help.It was my mistake that I did not read the version name right at first and used C3.5.2.5 instead of the .STM  one. I updated the firmware and now it is connected to aws.